# aws instance not allowing port 80 into my machine

Tags: networking, tcp, amazon-web-services

on my instance i run telnet my own ip address 80  iget telnet: unable to connect to remote host
all security groups are open 
ALL 0.0.0.0/0   Delete
please help

Comment: Do you have port 80 open in your iptables config?

Comment: You need to make sure port 80 is open on the OS as well - Add the exception into Windows Firewall, or iptables or whichever firewall your OS uses.

Comment: yes i gave copy of my security group

Comment: it is instance of ubuntu and gave this as command  sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Comment: which webserver did you install? Are you sure its running?

Comment: also ran this on my local machine  sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Are you trying to telnet *to* the instance *from the same* instance, using the public IP address?

Comment: yes i am running telnet from my host to my host using public i.p. from internal ip it happened instantly

Answer (score 0):

The public IP address is not actually bound to your instance's IP stack; instead, it's mapped using network address translation, which is provided by the AWS infrastructure.

It's not at all uncommon in any 1:1 NAT configuration that a host can't access itself by its own externally-mapped IP address.

I had never tried it in EC2 -- there's no reason to try it that I can think of, since you wouldn't want to use code that depended on an arbitrary external mapping, and "verifying" that a host could see itself wouldn't be verifying much -- but I can confirm that this is the way my instances behave, also.  They work fine from the Internet but they can't see themselves via their public IP.

However... you will find that you *can* access your host, from itself, by its external DNS name.

This is because within EC2, there is some automatic magic for handling DNS resolution of names, like ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com, where xx.xx.xx.xx is your external IP address.  (Formats may vary, you can find this address in the console.)  If you look that address up in DNS from outside of your own EC2 deployment, it returns the external IP address.  If you look it up inside EC2, it returns your *internal* IP address.

Comment: but i still cant browse to it

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question.  What happens when you try to telnet to port 80 on the instance... from somewhere other than the instance?  connection timed out?  connection refused?  Do you have "ICMP Echo Request" allowed from 0.0.0.0 in the security group, so that you can try pinging it from outside?

Comment: it has all traffic opened ALL 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: My mistake, I see that in your question.  So, what are the pinging and telnetting to port 80 results you get when you try from *outside* of EC2?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Security Group` at `console.aws.amazon.com`.

```
Create a new rule: ALL TCP 
Source: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Finally, `Add Rule` and `Apply Rule Changes`.